# translate text from english to another language in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-translate

I have use google api 

`"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=&target=ar&q=hello"`

but it gives response like this

`"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}`

i read in google group that it's now paid.is it true?
If it's true now what is option for that.

Answer (score 1):

yes, google translate is not free since version 2

try to use Microsoft translate http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/